# find all child tables (dependencies flowing inward) using doctrine

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

so if i have a model Student, which Tests and Homework reference, is there a way using the Model or Table class of Student which returns Tests and Homework? Essentially I want to manually do "on delete cascade" without necessarily knowing the tables Ineed to delete -- I was hoping to get these tables from one of Doctrine's methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the relations of a class with:

```
$relations = Doctrine_Core::getTable('<CLASS_NAME>')->getRelations();

foreach($relations as $relation)
  echo $relation->getClass();
```

See `Doctrine_Relation_Association` and `Doctrine_Relation` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

you can use also:

```
$relations = Doctrine_Core::getTable('Student')->findAll();

foreach($relations as $relation)
  echo $relation->getTests();
```

Comment: This way you get the objects, not the relations.